# Error! libgsttag-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_type_find_helper_get_range_full'

Tags: linux, build, gstreamer, undefined-reference

I have been trying to build a node which uses GStreamer and gst-plugins-bad. I am encountering the following build error, and I cannot seem to figure out what to do to resolve the issue. Any direction is greatly appreciated if you require more information please ask and I'll see what I can provide.

```
Errors     << node_cameras:make /home/xavier/catkin_ws/logs/node_cameras/build.make.021.log          
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.4.6, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.6, may conflict with libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2
**//usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_type_find_helper_get_range_full'**
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/xavier/catkin_ws/devel/.private/node_cameras/lib/node_cameras/node_cameras_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/node_cameras_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
cd /home/xavier/catkin_ws/build/node_cameras; catkin build --get-env node_cameras | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=6,7 -j; cd -
```

Comment: the _warnings_ are about a potential version conflict. -- the _failure_ is an `undefined reference` error that has nothing to do with opencv.